# Algorithm: Generate path for a Knight move to all Chess Board Squares

Tags: javascript, algorithm

## Problem description

I am trying to get an algorithm that will find the path of a possible sequence of moves that a Knight can move in a chessboard and visit all squares without repeating any of the squares. This is possible as illustrated by the diagram below

[image]

## My Approach

To try and achieve this I have followed the below steps

1. Created an array with `allSquares` `['a1', 'a2', 'a3', ..., 'h7', 'h8']`
2. Created another array of `visitedSquares`. initialy this is empty `[]`
3. Created a function an array of `paths` for each square. This represents squares to which a Knight can move from other squares

```json
{
  "a8": ["c7", "b6"],
  "a7": ["c6", "b5","c8"],
  "a6": ["c5","b4","c7","b8"],

  ...
  "h3": ["f2","g1","f4","g5"],
  "h2": ["f1","f3","g4"],
  "h1": ["f2","g3"]
}
```

4. Created a `getNextNode()` function to return the maximum of the cost of nodes visited
5. Finally I try to solve for the longest path with the below steps

```typescript
    while (this.squaresNotVisited.length > 0) {
      const nextTerm = this.getNextNode();
      const currentCost = this.pathCosts[nextTerm[0]];
      const nextPaths: string[] = this.paths[nextTerm[0]];
      nextPaths.forEach(square => {
        if (this.pathCosts[square] < currentCost + 1) {
          this.pathCosts[square] = currentCost + 1;
        }
      });

      this.squaresVisited = [...this.squaresVisited, nextTerm[0]];
      this.squaresNotVisited = this.allSquares.filter(
        x => !this.squaresVisited.includes(x)
      );
    }
```

Below is the complete Javascript code

```js
class AppComponent {
  board = {
    columns: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
    rows: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  };
  allSquares = this.board.columns.reduce(
    (prev, next) => [...prev, ...this.board.rows.map(x => next + x)],
    []
  );

  currentKnightPosition = "h5";
  squaresVisited = [];
  squaresNotVisited = [...this.allSquares];
  nextPossibleKnightPosition = currentKnightPosition => {
    const row = this.board.columns.indexOf(currentKnightPosition[0]);
    const column = Number(currentKnightPosition[1]) - 1;
    return [
      [column - 1, row - 2],
      [column - 1, row + 2],
      [column - 2, row - 1],
      [column - 2, row + 1],
      [column + 1, row - 2],
      [column + 1, row + 2],
      [column + 2, row - 1],
      [column + 2, row + 1]
    ]
      .filter(
        ([row, column]) => column >= 0 && column < 8 && row >= 0 && row < 8
      )
      .map(
        ([row, column]) =>
          this.board.columns[column] + this.board.rows[8 - row - 1]
      );
  };

  paths = this.allSquares.reduce(
    (prev, next) => ({
      ...prev,
      [next]: this.nextPossibleKnightPosition(next)
    }),
    {}
  );

  isNextSquare = square =>
    this.nextPossibleKnightPosition(this.currentKnightPosition).includes(
      square
    );
  costs = { [this.currentKnightPosition]: 0 };
  pathCosts = {
    ...this.allSquares.reduce(
      (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, [next]: -Infinity }),
      {}
    ),
    [this.currentKnightPosition]: 0
  };

  getNextTerm = () => {
    let nonVisted = Object.entries(this.pathCosts).filter(
      ([x, y]) => !this.squaresVisited.includes(x)
    );

    const maxPath = Math.max(...Object.values(nonVisted.map(([, x]) => x)));
    return nonVisted.find(([, x]) => x === maxPath);
  };
  costsCalc = () => {
    while (this.squaresNotVisited.length > 0) {
      const nextTerm = this.getNextTerm();
      const currentCost = this.pathCosts[nextTerm[0]];
      const nextPaths = this.paths[nextTerm[0]];
      nextPaths.forEach(square => {
        if (this.pathCosts[square] < currentCost + 1) {
          this.pathCosts[square] = currentCost + 1;
        }
      });

      this.squaresVisited = [...this.squaresVisited, nextTerm[0]];
      this.squaresNotVisited = this.allSquares.filter(
        x => !this.squaresVisited.includes(x)
      );
    }
  };

  ngOnInit() {
     this.costsCalc();
      console.log(Math.max(...Object.values(this.pathCosts)))
    
  }
}

const app = new AppComponent();
app.ngOnInit()
```

## The Problem

The Approach returns that the longest path is 51... which is incorrect as the number of squares are 64. I am stuck at whether the error is in my code or the error is in the approach I am using. Below is also a [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chessboard-knight-to-all-squares?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This wikipedia article mentions a simple heuristics (Warndorff's rule): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff's_rule. If your chess board size is 8x8 then you can always find a solution for it, I'm not sure about larger board. You can also look at this site for some more pseudocode: https://bradfieldcs.com/algos/graphs/knights-tour/

Comment: if I do `console.log(this.pathCosts)` then I see that there are no 1,2,3 etc and multiple of other, is that correct?

Comment: @Surt paths is an object{
  "a8": [
    "c7",
    "b6"
  ],
  "a7": [
    "c6",
    "b5",
    "c8"
  ],
  "a6": [
    "c5",
    "b4",
    "c7",
    "b8"
  ],

Comment: If I am in square a8 then the available paths are c7 and b6, same to a7. path will be c6, b5, c8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You're function gets stuck

In each step your method just takes the longest path and updates all its neighbors. It's not undoing decisions, that's why it gets stuck at a path length of 52.

It is essential that you go back, when you find out your current solution does not work, i.e. [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

#### Possible implementation

...using [Warnsdorff's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff%27s_rule).

```js
const findPath = (knightPosition) => {
  if (squaresVisited.size === allSquares.length - 1) return [knightPosition]

  squaresVisited.add(knightPosition)
  const neighbors = paths[knightPosition]
    .filter(neighbor => !squaresVisited.has(neighbor))
    .map(neighbor => {
      const neighborCount = paths[neighbor]
        .filter(square => !squaresVisited.has(square))
        .length
      return {
        position: neighbor,
        count: neighborCount
      }
    })
  const minNeighborsCount = Math.min(...neighbors.map(({ count }) => count))
  const minNeighbors = neighbors.filter(neighbor => neighbor.count === minNeighborsCount)
  for (const minNeighbor of minNeighbors) {
    const { position, count } = minNeighbor
    const path = findPath(position)
    if (path) return [knightPosition, ...path]
  }
  squaresVisited.delete(knightPosition)
}
```

#### Full working example

```js
const board = {
  columns: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
  rows: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
};

const allSquares = board.columns.reduce(
  (prev, next) => [...prev, ...board.rows.map(x => next + x)],
  []
);

const nextPossibleKnightPositions = currentKnightPosition => {
  const row = board.columns.indexOf(currentKnightPosition[0]);
  const column = Number(currentKnightPosition[1]) - 1;
  return [
    [column - 1, row - 2],
    [column - 1, row + 2],
    [column - 2, row - 1],
    [column - 2, row + 1],
    [column + 1, row - 2],
    [column + 1, row + 2],
    [column + 2, row - 1],
    [column + 2, row + 1]
  ]
    .filter(
      ([row, column]) => column >= 0 && column < 8 && row >= 0 && row < 8
    )
    .map(
      ([row, column]) =>
        board.columns[column] + board.rows[8 - row - 1]
    );
};

const paths = allSquares.reduce(
  (prev, next) => ({
    ...prev,
    [next]: nextPossibleKnightPositions(next)
  }),
  {}
);

const squaresVisited = new Set();

const findPath = (knightPosition) => {
  if (squaresVisited.size === allSquares.length - 1) return [knightPosition]

  squaresVisited.add(knightPosition)
  const neighbors = paths[knightPosition]
    .filter(neighbor => !squaresVisited.has(neighbor))
    .map(neighbor => {
      const neighborCount = paths[neighbor]
        .filter(square => !squaresVisited.has(square))
        .length
      return {
        position: neighbor,
        count: neighborCount
      }
    })
  const minNeighborsCount = Math.min(...neighbors.map(({ count }) => count))
  const minNeighbors = neighbors.filter(neighbor => neighbor.count === minNeighborsCount)
  for (const minNeighbor of minNeighbors) {
    const { position, count } = minNeighbor
    const path = findPath(position)
    if (path) return [knightPosition, ...path]
  }
  squaresVisited.delete(knightPosition)
}

const path = findPath("h5");
console.log(path)

allSquares.forEach(square => {
  squaresVisited.clear()
  const path = findPath(square)
  if(path.length !== 64) throw new Error(sqaure)
})
console.log("Works for all squares")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately if I try to implement this it keeps crushing my app

Comment: You're absolutely right! This thing takes forever to compute, because this problem isn't too easy to solve with backtracking alone. You could try to optimize it by using more suited data structures or searching more efficiently (like pruning impossible paths earlier or using heuristics like mentioned in the comments above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff's_rule)

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the Warnsdorff's rule.